# Int extension not applied to raw negative values

Tags: swift, types

My extensions to the `Int` type do not work for raw, negative values. I can work around it but the failure seems to be a type inference problem. Why is this not working as expected?

I first encountered this within the application development environment but I have recreated a simple form of it here on the Playground. I am using the latest version of Xcode; Version 6.2 (6C107a).

[image: Playground capture]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `-` is interpreted as the minus operator applied to the integer `2`, and not as part of the `-2` numeric literal.

To prove that, just try this:

```
-(1.foo())
```

which generates the same error

> Could not find member 'foo'

The message is probably misleading, because the error is about trying to apply the minus operator to the return value of the `foo` method.

I don't know if that is an intentional behavior or not, but it's how it works :)

Comment: The compiler will not allow the minus operator on UInt values because of potential overflow conditions; "Cannot invoke '-' with an argument of type 'Uint'".

Comment: That is a good test. The foo method must be taking precedence over the minus operator so it is being applied first to the unsigned 2 literal. Since there is no extension to UInt, it fails. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely a compiler bug (report on radar if you like). Use brackets:

```
println((-2).foo())
```